# Python Line continuation dictionary

Tags: python

I have a function that needs to return the call to another function that have some parameters. Let's say, for example, the following:

```
def some_func():
   iss = do_something()
   example = do_something_else()

   return some_long_name('maybe long string', {'this': iss, 'an': example, 'dictionary': 'wich is very long'})
```

I want to adjust it so it will comply with PEP 8. I tried:

```
def some_func():
   iss = do_something()
   example = do_something_else()

   return some_long_name('maybe long string', {'this': iss,
                                               'an': example,
                                               'dictionary': 'wich is very long'})
```

But it still goes way beyond 80 characters. So I did a two step 'line continuation', but don't know if it's how it's done.

```
def some_func():
   iss = do_something()
   example = do_something_else()

   return some_long_name('maybe long string',
                         {
                             'this': iss,
                             'an': example,
                             'dictionary': 'wich is very long'
                         })
```

Or should it be something like:

```
def some_func():
   iss = do_something()
   example = do_something_else()

   return some_long_name('maybe long string',
                         {'this': iss,
                          'an': example,
                          'dictionary': 'wich is very long'})
```

I would appreciate some insight so I can maintain a better code because PEP8 doesn't explain it very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, use Explaining Variables or Summary Variables express the dict. I like this coding style as follows.

```
keyword = {
    'this': iss,
    'an': example,
    'dictionary': 'wich is very long',
}
return some_long_name('maybe long string', keyword)
```

Answer (score 1):

PEP-0008 suggests this approach (see the first example group there):

```
return some_long_name(
    'maybe long string',
    {'this': iss,
     'an': example,
     'dictionary': 'wich is very long'})
```

As for the dict formatting style, in my opinion, not having lines with only braces on them is more readable, navigatable and editable.  The PEP does not mention any specific style for dict formatting.